# API documentation issue using grape-swagger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, ruby-grape

I am trying to use grape-swagger gem for creating the auto-generated documentation for my Grape API.

Using `'grape'` gem I have created few APIs.

**Example:**

http://localhost:9292/api/v1/charges

This API is working fine.

Following documentation of '[grape-swagger'](https://github.com/tim-vandecasteele/grape-swagger), I am not able to generate the API documentation properly.

My steps:

1. I added below in the gemfile

   gem 'grape-swagger'
2. I also used rack-cors to enable CORS by adding below in config.ru

   require 'rack/cors'
   use Rack::Cors do
   allow do
   origins '*'
   resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [ :get, :post, :put, :delete, :options ]
   end
   end

Also added below in gemfile.

```
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
```

3. Also I added below at the end in my API class

   add_swagger_documentation

But when I run http://localhost:9292/api/v1/swagger_doc, I am not getting the proper paths.
I need the API path like http://localhost:9292/api/v1/charges, but it is returning as http://localhost:9292/api/v1/swagger_doc/charges

Do I need to set any other configuration?

Answer (score 1):

In end of api class add below params for hide documentation path:

```
add_swagger_documentation hide_documentation_path: true, api_version: 'v1'
```

If you want to use this gem [grape-swagger-rails](https://github.com/BrandyMint/grape-swagger-rails) then use this configuration as per documentation:

Then create file named config/intializers/swagger.rb and add this line for customization:

```
GrapeSwaggerRails.options.url      = "/api/v1/swagger_doc"
GrapeSwaggerRails.options.app_url  = "#{ENV['APPLICATION_URL']}"
```

where you can set APPLICATION_URL in environment variables like : `localhost:3000`

And your config/routes.rb file set route as

```
mount GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine => '/swagger'
```

Then you can access all docs from here: `localhost:3000/swagger`

This way you can customize your swagger documentation with grape api.

Comment: Thanks Sachin! If I add hide_documentation_path: true, API path for swagger_doc is removed. But I am concerned as I am not getting localhost:9292/ap1/v1/charges because it is returning as localhost:9292/api/v1/swagger/charges. Is there any way out or I am doing any mistake?

Comment: I followed all instructions as described above and I am getting following error:

failed to parse JSON/YAML response